# how to ssh to ngrok self hosted server

Tags: ssh, ngrok

I follow this page to **SELF HOSTED** ngrok on my server (ngrok 1.7)
https://www.svenbit.com/2014/09/run-ngrok-on-your-own-server/

ATM, I can use the http protocol normally.
However, I want to use the ssh (tcp protocol) as well.
When try with below command

```
./ngrok -config=ngrok.cfg -proto tcp 22
```

> ngrok
>   (Ctrl+C to quit)
>
> Tunnel Status                 online
>   Version                       1.7/1.7
>   Forwarding                    tcp://tunnel.mydomain.com:38005 -> 127.0.0.1:22
>   Web Interface                 127.0.0.1:4040
>
> # Conn                        0
>
> Avg Conn Time                 0.00ms

The url format is quite differrent from provided ngrok (v2.x).

> Forwarding tcp://0.tcp.ngrok.io:36428 -> localhost:22

I think that the ssh is exposed correctly but have no idea how to connect.
Can you please show me the exact command to connect?

I try with below command but cannot success

```
ssh myuser@tunnel.mydomain.com -p 38005
```

> ssh: connect to host tunnel.mydomain.com port 38005: Connection timed out

Comment: Devote the question without reason does not help. Please elaborate when you do that.

Answer (score 0):

It's due to the firewall issue. I have to open the port 38005 on ngrok server and ssh words flawlessly (with above command).

However, it's not a good idea that we have to open the port that base on the previous ngrok commmand.
Do you guys know whether we can fix the port for tcp request?

Comment: Di you accomplished that with version 1.7?

Comment: What do you have on your config.cfg?

Answer (score 0):

found this SE and the solution linked below in August 2022.
https://www.endtoend.ai/tutorial/ngrok-ssh-forwarding/
(published in Sept 2020)  it uses snap for an easier ngrok install

https://snapcraft.io/install/ngrok/ubuntu

there's also this duplicate SE question. I like the ngrok.service  solution.

[How to keep ngrok running even when signing off of a server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50681671/how-to-keep-ngrok-running-even-when-signing-off-of-a-server)

worth noting you can use the ngrok.com dashboard to see your servers public ip.

https://dashboard.ngrok.com/tunnels/agents

Comment: there's also this git repo > https://github.com/vincenthsu/systemd-ngrok

Comment: I ended up using tmux as I couldn't get ngrok to start as a service. was not able to debug the reason for service failure.