# using free ngrok as a windows service

Tags: ngrok

What actually worked for me was:

download ngrok normal/free service, and put it in your path
download the authkey once you create an account, and set it w/ "ngrok authtoken " => this creates a file under your home/.ngrok folder

setup a service with nssm (install nssm from Admin\PowerShell w/ choco install nssm):

nssm install ngrok

in the service setup window, add executable "cmd.exe" w/ parameters: /K ngrok tcp 1234

in the newly installed service, change the login user to be your current one. this way, when service starts, ngrok can fetch the auth key from the user's home dir.

is there a better way?

Comment: Try reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50681671/how-to-keep-ngrok-running-even-when-signing-off-of-a-server) question, I found it pretty helpful

Comment: In Windows, after installing nssm with 'choco install nssm', this worked for me: nssm install YourServiceName cmd.exe /K ngrok http --config="C:\path\to\your\config\.ngrok2\ngrok.yml" --region=us --hostname=my.speficic.hostname.com 443